# Applying reflection to switch statement with an object

Tags: java, reflection, switch-statement

I'm trying to apply reflection to this switch statement. All of the examples that I have been able to find only only work for strings. In this case "art" is an object.

```
    public static EnumArt BukkitToNotch(Art art) {

    switch (art) {
        case KEBAB: return EnumArt.KEBAB;
        case AZTEC: return EnumArt.AZTEC;
        case ALBAN: return EnumArt.ALBAN;
        case AZTEC2: return EnumArt.AZTEC2;
        case BOMB: return EnumArt.BOMB;
        case PLANT: return EnumArt.PLANT;
        case WASTELAND: return EnumArt.WASTELAND;
        case POOL: return EnumArt.POOL;
        case COURBET: return EnumArt.COURBET;
        case SEA: return EnumArt.SEA;
        case SUNSET: return EnumArt.SUNSET;
        case CREEBET: return EnumArt.CREEBET;
        case WANDERER: return EnumArt.WANDERER;
        case GRAHAM: return EnumArt.GRAHAM;
        case MATCH: return EnumArt.MATCH;
        case BUST: return EnumArt.BUST;
        case STAGE: return EnumArt.STAGE;
        case VOID: return EnumArt.VOID;
        case SKULL_AND_ROSES: return EnumArt.SKULL_AND_ROSES;
        case FIGHTERS: return EnumArt.FIGHTERS;
        case POINTER: return EnumArt.POINTER;
        case PIGSCENE: return EnumArt.PIGSCENE;
        case BURNINGSKULL: return EnumArt.BURNINGSKULL;
        case SKELETON: return EnumArt.SKELETON;
        case DONKEYKONG: return EnumArt.DONKEYKONG;
        case WITHER: return EnumArt.WITHER;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(art);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to do this with reflection?

Comment: `I'm trying to apply reflection to this switch statement.` doesn't mean anything. Please clarify.

Comment: Where is the reflection here? And why you need reflection here? What you want to do?

Comment: We want to get rid of the switch statement. So basically do throw catch statement that covers all the cases.

Comment: @Bohemian not sure we don't have access to that class.

Comment: You can tell if it's an enum or not. Just print `Art.class.isEnum()` and `EnumArt.class.isEnum()` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EnumArt` and `Art` are both `enums` You don't need reflection, just use the `enum` API:

```
public static EnumArt BukkitToNotch(Art art) {
    try {
        return EnumArt.valueOf(art.name()); 
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) 
         throw new AssertionError(art);
    }
}
```

If Art isn't an enum, use whatever String attribute works to match the name.

If neither are enums, you should convert them to enums.

Comment: Ok, so we know Art does have a name() method. We believe Art and EnumArt are both enums.

This is the error we get for applying your solution:
    Tests in error: 
  testCraftArtToNotch(org.bukkit.ArtTest): No enum constant net.minecraft.server.EnumArt.KEBAB

Comment: I've added a try-catch to mimic switch code - try that. The error you're getting suggests the EnumArt enum doesn't have a KEBAB instance.

Comment: We already tried this and it returns a Failure instead of an error. Would it help to see the test?

Comment: You need to look at the source code and figure out what's going on. Also, you need to establush the purpose of the test. If you don't have access to the source code, there is no point testing the class, because you can't fix it if you find a problem.